# React: Pass data between non-hierarchical components?

Tags: reactjs

New to React, and have a very basic question about passing data between components. Everything I've researched about doing this assumes a hierarchical relation between components (parent/child, parent/grandchild, siblings). Two questions:

Can data be passed between two components that aren't in the same 'tree', two independent components?

I'm using React and React-Dom. Can this be done directly in React, without using another library (Redux, Mobx, etc.)?

JJ / Seattle

Comment: react is just a library for creating ui component, and redux,flux ... are for managing states and data.
u need to use them.

Answer (score 1):

React provides a utility called `Portals`

As per API definition:

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node
>   that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

More on this :

https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: Portals looks interesting. Right now, I'm rendering my app into a typical single DOM element: <div id="app"></div>. Portals would involve using a second DOM element?

Comment: You should only need one root element. You mentioned this: `Can data be passed between two components that aren't in the same 'tree', two independent components?`. Try to relate your DOM tree with the one in example.

Answer (score 0):

A common practice for passing data between two components in different trees is to create an EventBus.

https://github.com/arkency/event-bus

```
import EventBus from 'eventing-bus'
var callback = function(name) { console.log("Hello, " + name + "!"); };
EventBus.on("exampleEventName", callback);

import EventBus from 'eventing-bus';
EventBus.publish("exampleEventName", "Watson");
```

Comment: Event Bus looks nifty, but doesn't this fall into the "...using another library" category?